# Error while trying to access video url from arguments from pushNamed in flutter

Tags: flutter, runtime-error, video-streaming, video-player

I am trying to pass URL to `video controller` via `pushNamed` in flutter.

`error` i am facing is as followed

```
I/ExoPlayerImpl(29662): Release 2d82dca [ExoPlayerLib/2.9.6] [ASUS_X00T_2, ASUS_X00TD, asus, 28] [goog.exo.core]
I/flutter (29662): https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4
E/BufferQueueProducer(29662): [SurfaceTexture-0-29662-5] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
I/chatty  (29662): uid=10085(com.example.demo_app) JNISurfaceTextu identical 5 lines
E/BufferQueueProducer(29662): [SurfaceTexture-0-29662-5] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
D/SurfaceUtils(29662): disconnecting from surface 0x7b16f15010, reason disconnectFromSurface
I/ExoPlayerImpl(29662): Init 3c27ac9 [ExoPlayerLib/2.9.6] [ASUS_X00T_2, ASUS_X00TD, asus, 28]
I/OMXClient(29662): IOmx service obtained
D/SurfaceUtils(29662): connecting to surface 0x7b17399010, reason connectToSurface
I/MediaCodec(29662): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] setting surface generation to 30373895
D/SurfaceUtils(29662): disconnecting from surface 0x7b17399010, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
D/SurfaceUtils(29662): connecting to surface 0x7b17399010, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
I/ExtendedACodec(29662): setupVideoDecoder()
I/ExtendedACodec(29662): Decoder will be in frame by frame mode
D/SurfaceUtils(29662): set up nativeWindow 0x7b17399010 for 1280x720, color 0x7fa30c06, rotation 0, usage 0x20002900
W/MapperHal(29662): buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
W/MapperHal(29662): buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
I/OMXClient(29662): IOmx service obtained
I/ACodec  (29662): codec does not support config priority (err -2147483648)
I/ACodec  (29662): codec does not support config priority (err -2147483648)
I/ACodec  (29662): codec does not support config operating rate (err -2147483648)
W/ExtendedACodec(29662): Failed to get extension for extradata parameter
W/MapperHal(29662): buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
D/SurfaceUtils(29662): set up nativeWindow 0x7b17399010 for 1280x720, color 0x7fa30c06, rotation 0, usage 0x20002900
W/MapperHal(29662): buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
I/chatty  (29662): uid=10085(com.example.demo_app) CodecLooper identical 1 line
W/MapperHal(29662): buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
W/MapperHal(29662): buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
W/MapperHal(29662): buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
I/flutter (29662): https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4
I/flutter (29662): https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4
I/flutter (29662): https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4
I/flutter (29662): https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4
I/flutter (29662): https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4
I/flutter (29662): https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4
I/flutter (29662): https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4
I/flutter (29662): https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4
I/flutter (29662): https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4
Lost connection to device.
```

code for the `DemoShowScreen` is as followed

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../models/show.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class DemoShow extends StatefulWidget {

  static const id = "show_show_screen";

  @override
  _DemoShowState createState() => _DemoShowState();
}

class _DemoShowState extends State<DemoShow> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;
  Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;
  Show data;

  var media;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // Create and store the VideoPlayerController. The VideoPlayerController
    // offers several different constructors to play videos from assets, files,
    // or the internet.
      media = 'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4';
      _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(media);      
      // Initialize the controller and store the Future for later use.
      _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();

      // Use the controller to loop the video.
      _controller.setLooping(false);


    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Ensure disposing of the VideoPlayerController to free up resources.
    _controller.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    data = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    setState(() {
      media = data.mediaUrl;
      print(media);
    });
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('${data.title}', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,),
      ),
      // Use a FutureBuilder to display a loading spinner while waiting for the
      // VideoPlayerController to finish initializing.
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              FutureBuilder(
                future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                    // If the VideoPlayerController has finished initialization, use
                    // the data it provides to limit the aspect ratio of the video.
                    return AspectRatio(
                      aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                      // Use the VideoPlayer widget to display the video.
                      child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                    );
                  } else {
                    // If the VideoPlayerController is still initializing, show a
                    // loading spinner.
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // Wrap the play or pause in a call to `setState`. This ensures the
          // correct icon is shown.
          setState(() {
            // If the video is playing, pause it.
            if (_controller.value.isPlaying) {
              _controller.pause();
            } else {
              // If the video is paused, play it.
              _controller.play();
              _controller.seekTo(Duration(seconds: 32));
            }
          });
        },
        // Display the correct icon depending on the state of the player.
        child: Icon(
          _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
        ),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

What I am trying to replace the `butterfly.mp4` URL with `bee.mp4` URL which I got from the pushNamed arguments.

On-screen I can see the `butterfly.mp4` frame in video player but it never plays or update with `bee.mp4`

also, I tried calling the `ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;` in `initState` but end up with `null` so that code is been removed.

### edit after updating code

the video frame changed to current video but i am still facing the issue for playing video.

New Code with `Stateless Widget`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../models/demo.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class DemoShowScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const id = "demo_show_screen";
  VideoPlayerController _controller;
  Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Show data = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(data.mediaUrl);
    _controller.setLooping(false);  
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: _controller.initialize(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  // If the VideoPlayerController has finished initialization, use
                  // the data it provides to limit the aspect ratio of the video.
                  return AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                    // Use the VideoPlayer widget to display the video.
                    child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                  );
                } else {
                  // If the VideoPlayerController is still initializing, show a
                  // loading spinner.
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Wrap the play or pause in a call to `setState`. This ensures the
            // correct icon is shown.

              // If the video is playing, pause it.
              if (_controller.value.isPlaying) {
                _controller.pause();
              } else {
                // If the video is paused, play it.
                _controller.play();
                _controller.seekTo(Duration(seconds: 32));
              }
          },
          // Display the correct icon depending on the state of the player.
          child: Icon(
            _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
          ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

error code :

```
I/ExoPlayerImpl(22057): Release 877cbe7 [ExoPlayerLib/2.9.6] [ASUS_X00T_2, ASUS_X00TD, asus, 28] [goog.exo.core]
E/BufferQueueProducer(22057): [SurfaceTexture-0-22057-1] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
I/chatty  (22057): uid=10085(com.example.demo_app) JNISurfaceTextu identical 5 lines
E/BufferQueueProducer(22057): [SurfaceTexture-0-22057-1] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
D/SurfaceUtils(22057): disconnecting from surface 0x7b17aa2010, reason disconnectFromSurface
I/ExoPlayerImpl(22057): Init cf82360 [ExoPlayerLib/2.9.6] [ASUS_X00T_2, ASUS_X00TD, asus, 28]
I/OMXClient(22057): IOmx service obtained
D/SurfaceUtils(22057): connecting to surface 0x7b337e0010, reason connectToSurface
I/MediaCodec(22057): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] setting surface generation to 22586371
D/SurfaceUtils(22057): disconnecting from surface 0x7b337e0010, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
D/SurfaceUtils(22057): connecting to surface 0x7b337e0010, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
I/ExtendedACodec(22057): setupVideoDecoder()
I/ExtendedACodec(22057): Decoder will be in frame by frame mode
D/SurfaceUtils(22057): set up nativeWindow 0x7b337e0010 for 1280x720, color 0x7fa30c06, rotation 0, usage 0x20002900
W/MapperHal(22057): buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
W/MapperHal(22057): buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
I/OMXClient(22057): IOmx service obtained
I/ACodec  (22057): codec does not support config priority (err -2147483648)
I/ACodec  (22057): codec does not support config priority (err -2147483648)
I/ACodec  (22057): codec does not support config operating rate (err -2147483648)
W/ExtendedACodec(22057): Failed to get extension for extradata parameter
W/MapperHal(22057): buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
W/MapperHal(22057): buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
D/SurfaceUtils(22057): set up nativeWindow 0x7b337e0010 for 1280x720, color 0x7fa30c06, rotation 0, usage 0x20002900
W/MapperHal(22057): buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
W/MapperHal(22057): buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
W/MapperHal(22057): buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
W/MapperHal(22057): buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Wrap your complete class in a StatelessWidget, because of initState is called before build method,

> Also avoid calling setState in your build function.

```
class WebViewPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ArgumentData data = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    return Scaffold(
body:DemoShow(data.url),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: still ended up with the same error, but the frame for video change to the current video. Code merged above

Comment: any help here ?